# xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove not removing all elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Please see the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for x in ("<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>", "<a><q /><b /><c><d /></c></a>", "<a><m /><q /><b /><c><d /></c></a>"):
    root = ET.fromstring(x)
    for e in root: root.remove(e)
    print(ET.tostring(root))
```

I expect it to output `<a></a>` in all instances but instead it gives:

```
b'<a><c><d /></c></a>'
b'<a><b /></a>'
b'<a><q /><c><d /></c></a>'
```

I totally don't grok this. I don't see any pattern to the specific elements that were removed either.

The documentation merely says:

> Removes subelement from the element. Unlike the find* methods this
>   method compares elements based on the instance identity, not on tag
>   value or contents.

What am I doing/assuming wrong? I am getting basically the same output with both Python 2.7.5 and 3.4.0 on Kubuntu Trusty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This demonstrates the problem:

```
>>> root = ET.fromstring("<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>")
>>> for e in root:
...     print(e)
... 
<Element 'b' at 0x7f76c6d6cd18>
<Element 'c' at 0x7f76c6d6cd68>
>>> for e in root:
...     print(e)
...     root.remove(e)
...
<Element 'b' at 0x7f76c6d6cd18>
```

So, modifying the object that you are iterating affects the iteration. This is not entirely unexpected, it is the same if you alter a list while iterating over it:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for i in l:
...     l.remove(i)
>>> print l
[2, 4]
```

As a workaround you can repetitively remove the first subelement like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for x in ("<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>", "<a><q /><b /><c><d /></c></a>", "<a><m /><q /><b /><c><d /></c></a>"):
    root = ET.fromstring(x)
    for i in range(len(root)):
        root.remove(root[0])
    ET.tostring(root)
```

Output

```
b'<a />'
b'<a />'
b'<a />'
```

This works because the iterator is not varying while the loop is executed.
 Or, if you want to remove all subelements of the root element ***and*** its all of its attributes, you can use `root.clear()`:

```
>>> root = ET.fromstring('<a href="blah"><b /><c><d /></c></a>')
>>> root.clear()
>>> ET.tostring(root)
b'<a />'
```

Comment: @VivekSable : thanks for the upvote! `clear()` is fine provided that it is OK to lose all of the attributes of the parent element.

Comment: `(  , "<a><q /><b /><c><d /></c></a>", "<a><m /><q /><b /><c><d /></c></a>")`  is invalid in `Python 2.7`, got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax
` exception. This is valid in `Python 3 +` ?

Comment: @VivekSable: thanks again for pointing out that typo :) ... fixed.

Comment: Welcome, I am learning Python, so checking your answer and try to clear my concept and my answer too.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks for the reply. Obviously I did not use `clear()` to avoid resetting all the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, get all children of root tag and remove one by one in reverse order

E.g.

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
In [2]: content = "<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>"
In [15]: root = ET.fromstring(content)
In [16]: for e in root.getchildren()[::-1]:
   ....:     print e
   ....:     root.remove(e)
   ....:     
<Element 'c' at 0xb60890ac>
<Element 'b' at 0xb608908c>

In [17]: ET.tostring(root)
Out[17]: '<a />'
```

---

With you code only one element is removed.
E.g.

```
In [21]: root = ET.fromstring(content)
In [22]: for e in root:
   ....:     print "Element:", e
   ....:     root.remove(e)
   ....:     
Element: <Element 'b' at 0xb608936c>

In [23]: ET.tostring(root)
Out[23]: '<a><c><d /></c></a>'
```

---

without reverse

```
In [45]: root = ET.fromstring(content)

In [46]: for e in root.getchildren():
   ....:     print "Elenment:", e
   ....:     root.remove(e)
   ....:     
Elenment: <Element 'b' at 0xb6219dcc>

In [47]: ET.tostring(root)
Out[47]: '<a>asas<c><d /></c></a>'
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no need to go in reverse order. Just `for e in root.getchildren(): root.remove(e)` was sufficient.

Comment: @jamadagni: without reverse is not working for me. Updated answer, please check and let me know how it is working for you.

Comment: Curiously, it is working in Py3 but not in Py2 which you seem to be using. Just verified on Py 2.7.6 vs 3.4.0 on my Kubuntu Trusty system. Try Py3 and see how it works for you. (NOTE: You'll have to use `print` as a function, in case you didn't know that already.)